# How to clear JS timers

Tags: javascript

I've got a user which i get from database. For each user is possible to reset his password. But it's possible only one time for three minutes. If password was reseted less than three minutes, I show timer with JS, which show how much time left for next reset and reset button is disabled. When countdown is finished, button become availiable and displayed inscription "Password reset avaliable". Because the each user has his own timer, when I select another user, previous timer must be stopped with reset() function, and must be started other timer. It's just the only one timer must be in one time.

Timer:

```
var timerCount = 0;


function startTimer(minute, second) {
    timerCount++;
    start(minute, second);
}

function start(minute, second) {
    disableButton('resetPasswordButton');
    var m = minute;
    var s = second;
    if (timerCount == 0) {
        document.getElementById('expiredTimeOutputText').innerHTML = "Password reset avaliable";
        m = 0;
        s = 0;
        enableButton('resetPasswordButton');
        return ;
    }
    if (s == 0) {
        if (m == 0) {
            reset();
            document.getElementById('expiredTimeOutputText').innerHTML = "Password reset avaliable!";
            enableButton('resetPasswordButton');
            return ;
        }
        m--;
        s = 59;
    } else
        s--;
    document.getElementById('expiredTimeOutputText').innerHTML = m + ":" + s;
    setTimeout(function () {
        start(m, s);
    }, 1000);
}


function reset() {
    if (timerCount > 0) {
        timerCount = 0;
    }
}


function enableButton(id){
    document.getElementById(id).disabled = false;
}

function disableButton(id){
    document.getElementById(id).disabled = true;
}
```

method to start timer on button click

```
public void changePassword() {
    RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    requestContext.execute("startTimer(\"0\", \"40\")");
    Date tmpDate = new Date();
    Long diff = tmpDate.getTime();
    mainDataBean.setResetTimer(applicantsTableSelectedRow.get("ID"), diff.toString());    
}
```

method to start timer on user change

```
public void checkTimerForNewUser() {
    RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Date tmpDate = new Date();
    Long currentTime = tmpDate.getTime();
    requestContext.execute("reset()");
    if (applicantsTableSelectedRow != null) {
        if (!mainDataBean.getResetTimer(applicantsTableSelectedRow.get("ID")).equals("noTimer")) {
            Long applicantTimerTime = Long.parseLong(mainDataBean.getResetTimer(applicantsTableSelectedRow.get("ID")));
            if (currentTime - applicantTimerTime > timerValue) {
                mainDataBean.deleteResetTimer(applicantsTableSelectedRow.get("ID"));
            }
            else {
                expiredTimeMinute = (timerValue - (currentTime - applicantTimerTime)) / 60000;
                expiredTimeSecond = (timerValue - (currentTime - applicantTimerTime)) / 1000 - expiredTimeMinute * 60;
                requestContext.execute("startTimer(\"" + expiredTimeMinute + "\", \"" + expiredTimeSecond + "\")");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If consistently reset user password, one after another, everything works fine. But if I consistently reset password for 5 users, and after that I return to first user with reseted password, if time isn't expired, I've got all 5 timers, which overlap one another, display 5 different times 5 time in second. But in theory they must stop because of reset function. How does it possible to make the only one timer exist? Do I stop functions wrong?

Example with clearTimeout:

```
function start(minute, second) {
    disableButton('resetPasswordButton');
    var m = minute;
    var s = second;
    if (timerCount == 0) {
        document.getElementById('expiredTimeOutputText').innerHTML = "Reset Button Available!";
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        enableButton('resetPasswordButton');
        return ;
    }
    if (s == 0) {
        if (m == 0) {
            reset();
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            document.getElementById('expiredTimeOutputText').innerHTML = "Reset Button Available!";
            enableButton('resetPasswordButton');
            return ;
        }
        m--;
        s = 59;
    } else
        s--;
    document.getElementById('expiredTimeOutputText').innerHTML = m + ":" + s;
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        start(m, s);
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clear timers with:

- [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout) for `setTimeout`
- [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) for `setInterval`

#### Example:

```js
// will *never* run since we clear it below, immediately after we
// create it.
var timeout = setTimeout(() => {  
  console.log('foo')
}, 1000)

clearTimeout(timeout)

// will run only *once* since we clear it when it's called
var interval = setInterval(() => {  
  console.log('bar')
  clearInterval(interval)
}, 1000)
```

Comment: In my function my timer alredy can stop, but then I start 5 timers for 5 different users, and when i go to user with activated timer - all timers start to work again. Otherwise only one timer works. I tried to use clearTimeout, it doesn't help, Timers start to work again

Comment: `clearTimeout`/`clearInterval` works for millions of people just fine since the early 00's. You're not using it correctly. Take the examples I posted above, extrapolate the concepts I use - most importantly assigning the timeout to a variable you hold on to - and apply it to your code. Happy debugging

Comment: Maybe. I added example with using clearInterval. Can you tell what's wrong with it?

Comment: It stopes correctly when I change user. And correctly starts another one. But if i return to user, where I already have timer, than is start all stopped timers again

Comment: You're probably starting new separate timers. Once a timer is cleared, it cannot be started again.

Comment: I don't know how it can be. in my checkTimerForNewUser method time is obtained from Map which contains times and ids, and transmitted as parameters to JS function. It happens only for one selected user, not for all map. And as I said, it happens only when I return to user, who already have started timer. If I go to user who doesn't, everything works fine. I can start 5 timers in a row for 5 different users, and everything will dislpay correctly